# Unresolved reference thread

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, kotlin, standard-library

I am attempting to spin up a new thread in kotlin for android, using `kotlin.concurrency.thread` However I keep getting:

```
 Unresolved reference: thread
```

I thought this was in the standard library?

Actual code:

```
fun identify(userId: Integer) {
    thread() {
      CustomExceptionHandler(context)
      DoStuffClass.doStuff(context, userId)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you added the stdlib for your jdk version? see here: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#kotlin-standard-library-artifacts-and-split-packages

Comment: yeah, i include kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 in my dependencies:

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

Answer (score 3):

The correct import statement is:

```
import kotlin.concurrent
```

The sample code should be:

```
fun identify(userId: Integer) {
    thread {
        CustomExceptionHandler(context)
        DoStuffClass.doStuff(context, userId)
    }
}
```

Because the `thread` function is defined as:

```
/**
 * Creates a thread that runs the specified [block] of code.
 *
 * @param start if `true`, the thread is immediately started.
 * @param isDaemon if `true`, the thread is created as a daemon thread. The Java Virtual Machine exits when
 * the only threads running are all daemon threads.
 * @param contextClassLoader the class loader to use for loading classes and resources in this thread.
 * @param name the name of the thread.
 * @param priority the priority of the thread.
 */
public fun thread(
    start: Boolean = true,
    isDaemon: Boolean = false,
    contextClassLoader: ClassLoader? = null,
    name: String? = null,
    priority: Int = -1,
    block: () -> Unit
): Thread {
    ...
}
```

As explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter), the `thread` function uses a lambda as the last parameter, then, by Kotlin syntax, a single parameter function didn't need the parenthesis, just the lambda block.